# Do eunuchs have something distinctive so people can tell them apart?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the first or second book, when Daenerys is in a city, she wants to enter a building ( I think) and she thinks:

> [...] and there was a eunuch guarding the door [...].

How could she understand that the person she saw (that she haven't seen before) was a eunuch? Do eunuchs have something distinctive so people can tell them apart?

Are they like Varys? Shaven head and no beard?

Comment: Her name is not Khaleesi, it is Daenerys. Her title is khaleesi, because she was married to *Khal* Drogo.

Comment: It’s more that they distinctively *lack* something...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's start with a definition of what a eunuch is:

> eunuch (noun): a man who has been castrated, especially (in the past) one employed to guard the women's living areas at an oriental court.

The key part being that they're castrated, often at a very young age. The result is that they wouldn't develop normally, would lack any sexual urges, wouldn't be capable of growing facial or body hair, and would also likely have a childish appearance (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castration#Medical_consequences)). Those are likely enough to make them visually distinguishable from whole men.

The other clue might be the nature of the building that Daenerys was entering. If it was the chambers for a woman, or a number of women, it's more likely that the guard outside would be a eunuch. The lack of sexual urges means there's no worry about them consorting with the women at all.

Comment: Also, they could have typical clothing, which could also tell them apart. If you see a modern valet in front of a hotel in his characteristic suit, you recognize him because of the suit *and* where he is standing. Just having the suit might not give him a away if he's not standing in front of a hotel, but if he stands there, the suit helps identifying him.

Comment: The also tend to be "plumper" > `“The Unsullied you may have seen in Pentos and Myr were household guards. That’s soft service, and eunuchs tend to plumpness in any case.` Arstan Whitebeard says this in *A Storm of Swords*

Answer (score 1):

Eunuch is a castrated person... his genitalia and or testies are removed...

No testicles means no production of male hormon called testosterone.

This means that a person that gets castrated doesnt develop "manly" features. Specialy if they got castrated while young  ( like in the books )...

Eg. no facial hair, not much hairgrowth on the body, no "anatomic bulge", a slightly femalish voice and/or slightly larger breasts on the account of too much estrogen!

Comment: This essentially repeats the (already accepted, and much more upvoted) answer.